# Inserir array vindo do ajax no banco mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tenho esse ajax que mostra os itens escolhidos nos "**checkbox**" do formulário.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#submit').click(function(){  
           var languages = [];  
           $('.get_value').each(function(){  
                if($(this).is(":checked"))  
                {  
                     languages.push($(this).val());  
                }  
           });  
           languages = languages.toString();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"form_cadastro.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{languages:languages},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#result').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });
```

**Html**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1"   class="get_value" name="redes_sociais">
<input type="checkbox" value="1"  class="get_value" name="site">
<input type="checkbox"  value="1" class="get_value" name="endereco">

<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST["languages"]))  
 {  

      echo $_POST["languages"];  
 }
```

Minha dúvida é como posso inserir no banco mysql os valores de cada input?

**Estrutura Mysql**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO planos (redes_sociais, site, endereco) VALUES

('".$_POST['redes_sociais']."', '".$_POST['site']."',".$_POST['endereco']."')";
```

Comment: Quando você envia o parâmetro languages via ajax, ele vai corresponder ao post, sabendo isso, preciso saber qual o valor de $_POST["languages"] para te ajudar.

Comment: esta na minha pergunta editei ela

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você quer, na parte de "Estrutura de Mysql", o que você deseja fazer exatamente?

> Minha dúvida é como posso inserir no BD

Você não sabe como tratar o valor de POST para enviar ou não sabe como fazer conexão com o BD para enviar, sua pergunta está com duplo sentido.

Comment: é que os valores dos checkbox aparece só com isso echo $_POST["languages"]; como eu poderia inserir no meu mysql?

Comment: É exatamente o que quero saber, qual o valor de $_POST["languages"], não tem na sua postagem, e, você está tratando isso no JS, enviando como parâmetro único para o PHP.

Comment: o valor vai ser sempre "1" quando selecionado. <input type="checkbox" value="1"   class="get_value" name="redes_sociais">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente o modo como você trata no JS está errado.

Seu código

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#submit').click(function(){  
           var languages = [];  
           $('.get_value').each(function(){  
                if($(this).is(":checked"))  
                {  
                     languages.push($(this).val());  
                }  
           });  
           languages = languages.toString();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"form_cadastro.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{languages:languages},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#result').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });
```

Novo código

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#submit').click(function(){  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"form_cadastro.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$("input").serialize(),  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#result').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });
```

Então você poderá tratar no PHP como `$_POST["atributo"]`

```
redes_sociais=1&site=1&endereco=1
```

Você pode alterar `$("input").serialize()` por `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: está retornando isso no console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: Esse erro deve ser por algum digitação errada, veja o exemplo no jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/0tk2mq4q/

Mostre seu novo código com a alteração que passei.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre, exatamente isso que ele precisava, só tem um errinho, que são as chaves no `data`, restante ta rodando liso

Comment: Putz! Acabei esquecendo de remover. Editada.

Comment: Até apaguei minha resposta, isso ai resolve tudo. Gratidao!